# Ugrading FullCalendar from version 1 to latest version 2.3.2 Moment _ordinalParse is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

While Ugrading `FullCalendar` from version 1 to latest version 2.3.2 I receive the error: `TypeError:this._ordinalParse is undefined.`

It worked prior to me upgrading.

This is when I click on a day to add a new event.

Here is the initialize calendar code.

```
    $('#calendarVehicleID1').fullCalendar({ 
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        height: 300,
        events:  {
            url: 'Calendar.cfc',
            data: function () {
                return {
                    method: 'getEvents',
                    vehicle: iVehicleID,
                    CustomerID: $('#CustomerID').val(),
                    ServiceCenterID: $('#ServiceCenterID'+iVehicleID).val()
                }
            },
            error: function() {}
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loadingVehicleID1').toggle(bool);
            if (!bool) {
                $('#Vehicle1_5').height($('#calendarVehicleID1').height());
                $('#Container2').height($('#calendarVehicleID1').height()+60);
            }
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
            element.addClass(event.className);
            element.attr('onclick', 'openCalendarUpdate("' + 
                event.title + '","' + 
                event.description + '","' + 
                event.startDate + '","' + 
                event.endDate + '","' + 
                event.customerid + '","' + 
                event.servicecenterid + '","' + 
                event.servicecentername + '","' + 
                event.productid + '","' + 
                event.location + '","' + 
                event.textreminder + 
            '");');
        },
        disableDragging: true,

        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            selectedCalendarDate = date;
            $('#dialog-enter-event').dialog('open');
            setEventDialogData();
            //openEventModal(date, 1);
        },


    });
```

I have the `moment.min.js` after the load of jquery and before the load of `fullcalendar.min.js`

Comment: Did you already check the [upgrading guide](http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/)?

Answer (score 0):

After applying the following code in the dayClick function it is now working.

```
    selectedCalendarDate = date.formatDate();
```